# (Python) What libraries are good for audio feature vector representation?

Tags: python, audio, vector, scikits

What Python libraries are recommended to complement with scikit learn (a machine learning library)?

I have .wav files that I would like to represent as feature vectors, so that I could perform audio recognition.

Is scikit.audiolab a good candidate?

It would be highly appreciated if a sample code or a reference is given, which reads a .wav file to a feature vector :).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, scikit.audiolab is merely for reading/writing audio files but I think in addition you'll want to look at the signal processing libraries in scipy to actually build your feature vectors.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html

Comment: Thanks, so you suggest first using audiolab to read an audio file to some variable 'a' on which I apply signal processing algorithms to get the feature vector?

Comment: I would say that things like essentia http://essentia.upf.edu/ which provide a python binding could be a good candidate to have nice audio descriptors.